# Toggle div - click on title or everywhere to close

Tags: jquery, html

I have two links which, when clicked, toggle two different divs.
I added a second function so that when you click outside the div, the div closes. This is my current code:

```
function toggleDiv(divId){
    $("#"+divId).toggle();

    $("body").click(function(){
        $("#bio").hide(0);
        $("#prj").hide(0);
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cxqL0ej9/

I'm no expert in jQuery, so I need help to rework the code.
At the moment, everything works but if I click on the link again, nothing happens (that's because it toggles the "hide" too, i think).
This is what I need:

- when you click on those two links, each hidden div shows up AND if you click again, it hides again
- when you click everywhere else, the visible div hides

Comment: could you please share a fiddle with us..

Comment: Could u please update your code with html...

Comment: You are right, here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/cxqL0ej9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
$(window).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click", function() {
    $(".toggle-menu-text").hide();
  });

  $("[data-id-target]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var targetId = $(this).data("id-target");
    var open = !$("#" + targetId).is(':visible');

    $(".toggle-menu-text").hide();

    if (open) {
      $("#" + targetId).show();
    } else {
      $("#" + targetId).hide();
    }
  });

  $(".toggle-menu-text").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.toggle-menu-text {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
}
.position-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.position-fixed.position-fixed-top {
  top: 10px;
}
.position-fixed.position-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 10px;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="position-fixed position-fixed-top text-center">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id-target="bio">Title</a>
  <div class="toggle-menu-text" id="bio">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore omnis eligendi neque nam quis numquam earum molestias similique modi quasi exercitationem amet, quas consectetur ratione officia ab. Ut, iusto, distinctio.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="position-fixed position-fixed-bottom text-center">
  <div class="toggle-menu-text" id="prj">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore omnis eligendi neque nam quis numquam earum molestias similique modi quasi exercitationem amet, quas consectetur ratione officia ab. Ut, iusto, distinctio.
  </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id-target="prj">Index</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works well, except for the fact that, when you have title or index open and you click on its title, it collapses and opens again!

Comment: what do you need ? Whe the user clicks Title/Index to open only ?

Comment: if title is closed, you click it and it opens, if it's open you click the title and it closes again!

Comment: Hmm if I understood well, no should work as you wanted

Comment: it does! Thanks a lot, that's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend something like this:

JQuery

```
$( // your element  ).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('cssToggle');
});

$("body").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('cssToggle');
});
```

CSS

```
// Element to hide
.cssToggle
{
   display: none;
}
```